# Can two-tape read-only Turing machines recognize any recursive language?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, computability, counter-automata

Suppose that a $k$-tape [read-only Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_Turing_machine) receives its input on each $k$ tapes.
It cannot write on the tapes, but it can move on them in both ways, even move off from the input.
So for example, it can simulate [counter machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine), which implies that it can recognize any recursive language if $k\ge 3$.
If $k=1$, then it can be simulated by a two-way DFA, thus can recognize only regular languages. But what happens for $k=2$?

> Can two-tape read-only Turing machines recognize any recursive language?

Note that two-counter machines exhibit an [intermediate behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine#Two-counter_machines_are_Turing_equivalent_(with_a_caveat)), but this doesn't seem to answer my question.
Nor does the answer to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19551/can-a-two-counters-machine-decide-n2), though the proof might not be much different.

Comment: How does such a machine simulate a counter machine?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: it can simulate a 2 counters machine if both tapes initially contain at least a marker. E.g. the first tape $\#\langle input \rangle$ second tape $\#$. A $+1$ in the counter machine is simulated moving the head to the right, a $-1$ is simulated moving the head to the left; the "zero"  test can be done checking if the head is on the marker.

Comment: @domotorp, Do you mean "Can two-tape read-only Turing machines recognize **every** recursive language?"

Comment: @Neal Yes. $~~~~~~$

Comment: Note that it is also (very) difficult to prove that your model when restricted to unary inputs is equivalent to the power of two counters automata; see my other (unsolved) old question on cstheory: [Conjecture about two counters automata](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/21525/3247). Clearly the conjecture is false in your model because it implicitly stores the original input as a "constant". At that time I also asked a few researchers about it (and also sent an email to Ibarra, but never got a solution :-)

Comment: I like this model, because it shows that Turing-machines are just as powerful without writing; for students, this is quite stunning.